# In-app billing с вариативными ценами android

Tags: android, in-app-purchases

Гугл сам представляет возможность продавать подписки и товары по фиксированной цене в мобильных приложениях. А можно ли через какие-нибудь сервисы или библиотеки предоставлять возможность покупать не статичный контент? Например, дать возможность оплачивать доставку еды, цена которой зависит от расстояния до ресторана? Чтобы пользователь мог заплатить, например, 304,64 руб. И если есть библиотеки/сервисы, то где проводить проверку всех покупок? Писать свой бэкэнд? Интересует конкретно андроид

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, Google не позволит Вам продавать что-то с динамической ценой.
А, если бы и мог позволить, то Вы бы быстро от этого отказались, т.к. Google берет комиссию в размере 30% (читать здесь [RU](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622?hl=ru) / [ENG](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622?hl=en)).

В качестве альтернативы Вы можете воспользоваться платежной системой [STRIPE для Android](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android).

И я Вам **настоятельно рекомендую** еще раз прочесть правила Google Play, чтобы в будущем не остаться без лицензии разработчика - [ЧИТАТЬ ЗДЕСЬ](https://play.google.com/intl/ru/about/developer-content-policy-print/)

Выкопировка специаально по Вашему вопросу - [Монетизация и реклама | Раздел "Платежи"](https://play.google.com/intl/ru_ALL/about/monetization-ads/payments/)

*Желаю Вам удачи в разработке продукта и интеграции платежной системы!* ;-)